# Excel Countif across multiple columns

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to count instances of two conditions across two columns of a same sheet. I am basically trying to count the number of data points that have one specific value for one column and one for an adjacent column like an AND logic.
 Can anyone suggest if there is someway i can do this with COUNTIF or do i need to use anything else?

Comment: The easiest way is to use countifS()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the countifs function wherein it will check multiple criteria. See the link for an example.

[Using Countifs function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF2YE.png)